# Choose to boot into linux from Windows 10 (dual boot without bootloader)

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bootloader

Given that I have installed both Windows 10 (primary) and Linux (secondary) in my disk, is there a way to boot into Linux by option inside Windows 10, maybe using 3rd party software?

I want to use the Linux installation rarely. As a result I don't want to have the bootloader screen delaying my boot by even a second. I can't use a VM because I'm running programs that make use cuda.

Comment: what linux do you use?

Comment: I could use Ubuntu but can use anything

Comment: Windows bootloader can only boot other Windows versions and there's no third-party tools to overcome that. As such Grub or similar must be used. That said, if your machine is UEFI and the OSes are installed in that mode (recommended) you can always boot Windows directly and independently from Grub just by setting it as the first boot entry in the firmware.

Answer (score 3):

You can use EasyBCD to tweak windows bootloader.

1. Install EasyBCD (Visual BCD Editor/ Bootice/ DualBoot pro all these are third party software which can be used for editing windows bootloader) and add entry for GRUB2 (which is the linux bootloader) to it and rewite mbr.
2. Then restart and boot into Linux OS.
3. Edit the grub file `(most probably /etc/default/grub or will be /etc/grub.d folder)`
4. Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0` and then execute command `sudo update-grub`.

Hope this may help. I Have used this method earlier in my system.

> (EasyBCD 2.3 works with Windows 10 also)

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you just have to edit your GRUB configuration files.

- Open your **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, press Enter and type in your password.
- Your grub file will (most likely) look like this:

  ```
  GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
  ```
- Change `GRUB_DEFAULT` to the number of your Windows OS in the bootloader list. Don't forget to save.
  (**Note:** the list starts at 0, then 1, and so on..)
- Then, run `sudo update-grub`.
  You computer should automatically boot to Windows 10.

If you need to open the bootloader in order to use Ubuntu, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while your computer is loading your bootloader.

For a more complex, detailed guide, go to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader.

Comment: As I commented above, if the system is UEFI, this is unnecessary and counterproductive. It's over-thinking what is in essence very simple with new systems.